# using transactions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, transactions

I have two tables in a database and when I add a product I need to insert in both tables. I think that i need to use transactions, but because I'm on the learning stage of CakePHP, SQL, etc...I'm stuck.

Those are my tables

```
products(id, name, description, price)  
images(id, path, alt, product_id)
```

and the method in the product model looks like this:

```
    function newProduct($product, $image){
    if(!empty($product) && !empty($image)){
        $dataSource = $this->getDataSource();
        $dataSource->begin($this);
        if($this->save($product)){
            ClassRegistry::init('Image');
            $Image = new Image();
            $Image->product_id = $this->id; 
                //I'm stuck here, how to save ??
            return  $dataSource->commit($this);
        }
        $dataSource->rollback($this);
    }

    return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Transactional behavior for CakePHP 1.2+:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Jippi/2007/01/29/transaction_behavior

Cake also has a `saveAll` method. Just specify both records in the same array and call saveAll:

```
$savearrary = array("Model1" => ..., "Model2" => ...);
$this->Model->saveAll($savearray);
```

(If you add Image to the `$uses` array (like = `var $uses = array("Image", "Product");`) you won't have to construct an Image object. The Image model will be accesible at $this->Image)